# How to make triggers based on the number of tables in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-trigger

I have 3 tables as below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AuditTrail]
(
    [AuditId] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [DateTime] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [TableName] [NVARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,
    [AuditEntry] [XML] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_AuditTrail] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
(
     [ID] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEWID()),
     [NameEmployee] [NVARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Transaction]
(
     [ID] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEWID()),
     [NameTransaction] [NVARCHAR](255) NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT [PK_Transaction] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (
)
```

And I've created 2 trigger for my table which handles some deletion, the trigger that I made working well. My trigger is below

```
CREATE TRIGGER AuditEmployee 
ON [dbo].[Employee]
AFTER INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted) > 0 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @AuditMessage XML
        SET @AuditMessage = (select * from deleted for xml auto) 

        INSERT INTO AuditTrail (DateTime, TableName, AuditEntry)  
        VALUES (GETDATE(), 'Simple', @AuditMessage)
    END
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER AuditTransaction 
ON [dbo].[Transaction]
AFTER INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM deleted) > 0 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @AuditMessage XML
        SET @AuditMessage = (select * from deleted for xml auto) 

        INSERT INTO AuditTrail (DateTime, TableName, AuditEntry)  
        VALUES (GETDATE(), 'Simple', @AuditMessage )
end

END
GO
```

In the query above I've created two triggers for two tables (Employee and Transaction). Data will be inserted into the AuditAll table if there is a deletion of data in both tables.

What I want to ask is, what if we have 10 tables, do I have to make 10 triggers? is it possible to make it in the stored procedure so that I don't manually make triggers based on the number of my table?

If possible, how to do it with a stored procedure? Please help :)

Comment: Why are you creating insert triggers that do nothing if the deleted table is empty? Seems that handling inserts is kind of silly. But to your question, a trigger is handling an event on a table. So if you want to track deletes from a given table then yes you would need a trigger on that table. If you delete from 10 tables you would need a trigger on each one you want to track. You could do this in your procedure using the OUTPUT clause but that won't capture deletes that happen outside your procedure.

Comment: You'll have to do 10 of something.  In a stored procedure you could store the `$action.deleted`  `OUTPUT` of a `merge` into a temp table and run a final insert into `audittrail`, but then you'd still be doing 10 `merge` statements inside the sproc.

Comment: Can you give me an example procedure to create triggers dynamically for my table above please? @TJB

Answer (score 0):

To do what you are doing so far, only with 10 tables, yes you do have to make 10 triggers.

You can generate the triggers dynamically in a number of different ways.  You can put your Table names in a Table variable and iterate through it in whatever way you are most comfortable (WHILE loop, CURSOR, OUTER APPLY) and build a sql string that incorporates the table name into the TRIGGER script you have and then execute it.

Since this is clearly an adhoc operation, I wouldn't worry about performance concerns with loops and cursors, just do whatever is easiest for you to write.

Comment: Can you give me an example loop query to create triggers dynamically for my table above please?

Comment: No I don't have an example of this handy.   If you attempt to write it and get an error, come back and post the error and your code as a new question and we will help with it.